# Convert List Item (list indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
myList = ['ABC1', 'DEF2', 'GHI3']
```

I also have a json file that I need to check two values, and if value1 is matching any item in the list, then extract the value2 and append to another list.

So here is the code:

```
myList = ['ABC1', 'DEF2', 'GHI3']

with open('myFile.json', 'r') as readFile:
     data = json.loads(readFile.read())
     for result in data['results']:
         value1 = (result['Categories']['value1'])
         value2 = (result['Categories']['value2'])

     for i in range(len(myList)):
         if myList[i] == value1:
             createArray.append(value2)
```

And this the error I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The error is because of this line:

```
if myList[i] == value1:
```

I tried `str(myList[i])` which usually works for me, but not this time. I can't get this resolved. Any advice?

Comment: Please use the standard 4 spaces of indentation, it's really hard to read your code with just one space.

Comment: That line can't get the error you show, since `i` is clearly an integer. Post the full traceback.

Comment: Why is the second `for` loop outside the first one? You're only using the last values of `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses on the lines that assign to `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed

Comment: Why do you need those parentheses?

Comment: Can you add the FULL traceback? I suspect `data` is actually a `list` as `myList[i]` won't actually produce that error.

Comment: Also why use `for i in range(len(myList)): if myList[i] == value1:`? I recommend `for i in myList: if i == value1:` or `for idx, val in enumerate(myList): if val == value1:` if you need to use the index later on.

Comment: FYI, you can simplify `json.loads(readFile.read())` to `json.load(readFile)`

Comment: I suspect `result['Categories']` is a list, not a dictionary. You need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is presumably coming from `result['Categories']['value1']`. `result['Categories']` is a list, not a dictionary, so you need to loop over it.

```
myList = ['ABC1', 'DEF2', 'GHI3']
createArray = []

with open('myFile.json', 'r') as readFile:
     data = json.loads(readFile.read())
     for result in data['results']:
        for category in result['Categories']:
            if category['value1'] in myList:
                value2 = category['value2']
                createArray.append(value2)
                if value2 == 'ABC':
                    # do something

print(createArray)
```

Comment: I need to be more specific. Like IF value2 == ABC1 do this...so basically I need to have List[i]

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: sorry I meant if value2 == myList[i]

Comment: Isn't that the same as `if value2 == value1:`?

Comment: Please show sample data and the desired result in the question. It's hard to figure it out from these piecemeal updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have not necessarily to convert `str(myList[i])` but the error says that there is an error with `int` data type in the list indices.

You have to convert the indices in `int` type.
You can check it with line `print(type(<index>))`

Comment: You mean using int(myList[i])

Comment: You need to check if the `i` index is really an integer and not a string like the `result` in the loop before.